# Time problem in prepared statement -> MySql

Tags: java

When I use the code below in a prepared statement

```
Date totalDate = visit.getTotalTime();
Date visitDate = visit.getVisitTime();

java.sql.Time sqlTotalTime = new java.sql.Time(totalDate.getTime() - visitDate.getTime()); 
ps.setTime(4, sqlTotalTime);
```

And I use these values

```
08/Dec/2010:07:27:54
08/Dec/2010:07:27:52
```

I would expect 00:00:02 but I get 01:00:02?

Anyone an idea why ....

Comment: Are you sure that are the values in visit? maybe in body of the constructor you do something which adds this hour? Can we have more code?

Comment: 10.120.10.101 - - [08/Dec/2010:07:27:52 1000] "GET /ELO/css/images/background-shadow.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.120.10.101 - - [08/Dec/2010:07:27:54 1000] "GET /ELO/qnx/leftHighlight.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - that's what in the log where I create the visit of. I parse the stuff and get the data above back when I use the methods. The difference I see is in MySql .... in Java it's no problem when I test I get 2 sec ?! It's something to do with the translation from Java to MySql

Comment: Then try the same but use sql.Date instead. and lets see if there will be the problem. Or maybe it has something to do with a time zone? add some more code, best build an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) presenting the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your trying to make a duration into a time. Two different concepts. When you create a Time instance it's tied to your timezone. If I'm on the east coast I get 19:00:02 local time but 00:00:02 GMT. If your looking for a true time then you'll have to add or subtract the difference between totalDate and visitDate to some know time value to get the Time value you want.